# SpringBootTest ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.yml]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have wriiten following test in spring boot application.

```
RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {UserServiceApplication.class,ApplicationConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class OAuthMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "abc";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "pin";

    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

    private static final String EMAIL = "abc@gamil.com";
    private static final String NAME = "abc";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    private String obtainAccessToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "password");
        params.add("username", username);
        params.add("password", password);

        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
                               .params(params)
                               .with(httpBasic(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
                               .accept(CONTENT_TYPE))
                               .andExpect(status().isOk())
                               .andExpect(content().contentType(CONTENT_TYPE));
        

        String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenNoToken_whenGetSecureRequest_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/users/email").param("email", EMAIL)).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    public void givenToken_whenPostGetSecureRequest_thenOk() throws Exception {
        final String accessToken = obtainAccessToken("nsandaruwa@wiley.com", "Jacaranda5");

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/users/email/{email}",EMAIL)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.principalId", is(NAME)))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
        
    }

}
```

but when I run the tests I am getting the following Application failed to load stack trace. and I also check
application.yml file is already placed in resource folder.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.wiley.aus.users.UserServiceApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.yml]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.yml]     at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:455)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:274)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Remove the `@PropertySource` annotation you have. Also ditch `@WebAppConfiguration` and your `@Before` method. Add `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` and `@Autowire` the `MockMvc`. Security will be setup automatically. Ideally you also remove the `classes` from `@SpringBootTest` (basically you are trying to work around all that in your test class).

Comment: i refer this tutorial to write test https://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Do you have application.yml in the folder test? In this path `src/test/resources/application.yml` Chech it. Also when you will run your application with Spring profile, for example, `SpringProfile=test`, your `application.yml` file's name should be `src/test/resources/application-test.yml`, With a spring profile name in the file's name.

Comment: i checked I have application.yml file in src/test/resources folder

Comment: try to change rename it from application.yml to application-dev.yml

Comment: i have used multi profile apparch in the application.yml ---
spring:
  profiles: dev

Comment: still i am getting the same exception